# How to create model variables based on database content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What I'm curious to get help with, is setting Model variables based on table data.

For example, In my database I may have a table of Facilities such as:

```
Toilet int, Sink int, Bath int, Rug string
```

Really bad example but yeah, these values may change in the database from form input or more facilities maybe added based on user input.

Now for me this isn't a problem, However what I would like to know is; in my model I `get;` and `set;` the values for `[HttpPost]` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(NewBooking model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return View("~/Views/Timetabler/Booking/Index.cshtml", model);
   }


   return View("~/Views/Timetabler/Booking/Index.cshtml", model);
}
```

So in my model I don't know what the variables would be, they could be Toilet, Sink etc but they could be somehting else therefore something like this wouldn't be suitable:

```
namespace build_01.Models.Timetabler
{
    public class NewBooking
    {
       public string Toilet { get; set; }

     }
}
```

How can I, if at all, create my  model variables based on database table content?

Comment: This can't be answered in a single SO answer. You need to learn about database normalization, ORMs and about MVC viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using Entity Framework to generate database models?
It really is quite simple and if you make a change to the database table, you can update the model in your project. 
If you already have a database, you would use a "Database First" approach. Make sure your database tables each have a Primary Key assigned to them.

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

In your application, right click your 'Models' folder > Add > New Item > **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** > **EF Designer From Database** ... Follow the steps on screen from here.

This will generate model classes that match the data types in your database. Oh, if your project doesnt already have Entity Framework, search for it in Nuget or check it on the Nuget repository.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/